# Recurring calendar entries in Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Does somebody know if it is possible to change one of documents in a series of recurring meetings?
I changed one of them with c# api and it changed all documents in the series (e.g. 5 docs in series will be modified during one save() call)

```
var document = view.GetFirstDocument();
if (document != null)
{
    do
    {
        var item = document.GetFirstItem("Repeats");
        var repeat = tmpItem != null ? Convert.ToInt32(tmpItem.Text) : 0;

        if(repeats)
        {
            document.ReplaceItemValue("myVal", "1"); //it change all my 5 docs after first save
            document.Save(true, false);
        }
        document = view.GetNextDocument(document);
    }
    while (document != null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "[Lotus Notes Calendar and Scheduling explained! Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/cs-pt1/)":

> the instance document of a repeating meeting can be split into multiple documents if the chair reschedules some instances. Consider a repeating meeting that repeats once a week for five weeks. If the chair advances the first and second instance by an hour, the single response document for all five instances is now split into two response documents: one for the first and the second instance and another for the remaining instances.

And from the "[IBM Lotus Notes and Domino Calendaring & Scheduling Schema](http://www.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc)":

> Repeating events are scheduled more than once over time and are represented by at least two notes in a parent-child relationship. The parent note is identified by its ApptUNID item (which is its note universal ID), and the child note is identified by the same ApptUNID as the parent and the original RepeatInstanceDates. The ApptUNID and RepeatInstanceDates items form a key pair of values that uniquely identify a particular repeat instance. More details are covered in the Repeat Model section of this paper.

So what you basically have to do is find the child Document of the event ($CSFlags conatins "i" and $Ref the parents UNID) and create a new (second) child document for the changed date/time, removing this particular date/time entry from the existing child document, IIRC.
In such cases, I always do that manually in the Notes Client and then compare the fields created that way with the ones I created via my code.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you loop through the view and change all documents that are available in the view. You need to pick the document you want to change.

EDIT:
A repeating entry is a document shown multiple times in a view. So it is possible that you are updating the same document multiple times. Compare the UniversalID of all the documents in the series to be sure.

If you change one of the entries using the Lotus Client it will ask if you want to update all, if you select "just this instance" the entry will be saved in a new document. So a repeating entry can be a single document or a combination of documents.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I loop over all documents in view - correctly. But with a change of first doc in a serie all docs are changed before i get these documents. I mean during one call of ReplaceItemValue("myVal", "1"); c# api changed whole serie

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  Replacing an item on one document will not affect other documents, and I can't think of any way you'd be setting off an agent or other triggered code that would be changing those other documents.  Just to be certain, I would see what happens when you take the do-while out of the code.

Comment: ok here is a code without do/while

`string id = "974E390DCF9D14F5C125793000468DA4"; ///first doc in serie
var d = UserDb.GetDocumentByUNID(id);
    d.ReplaceItemValue("mmRepeat", "");
    d.Save(true, true, true);`

Comment: c# api changed whole serie again

Comment: Are you sure it is not the same document? The repeating calender entry is actually a singe document shown multiple times. Only if you change the time on an entry it will be saved as a separate document.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice, and really the only advice, that I can give you is to study the LotusScript code in the mail template, and see exactly what it does when a user changes one entry in a repeating appointment.  Lotus has not documented it in any other way, but the template code is all open source and it is the ultimate authority.  Your task is to be compatible with what they do in the template -- otherwise it is pretty likely that your code will have side-effects that cause problems for users who try to use the Notes client to take additional actions on the calendar event series after your code has run.

Comment: Sorry, but there is actually very good documentation by IBM, the IBM Lotus Notes and Domino Calendaring & Scheduling Schema: http://www.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc

Comment: Ah, that's good then.  Was never available when I wanted it, but that was quite a while ago.  Thanks.